# while inserting data to a mysql database using Php. I'm getting an error saying Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'rate' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

1.Php code is as follows and i do not have an auto increment field
full error description

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO employee( emp_name, rate,
>   ifsc_code, acc_num, acc_holder_name) VALUES ( '', '', '', '', '').
>   Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'rate' at row 1

```
 <?php

include_once('connectdb.php');

$emp_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['emp_name']);
$rate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['rate']);
$ifsc_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['ifsc_code']);
$acc_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['acc_num']);
$acc_holder_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['acc_holder_name']); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(   emp_name, 
                                rate, 
                                ifsc_code, 
                                acc_num, 
                                acc_holder_name) 

        VALUES              (   '$emp_name', 
                                '$rate',
                                '$ifsc_code',
                                '$acc_num',
                                '$acc_holder_name')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Commodity added to inventory')</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=insert_emp_details.php'>";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: `''` is **NOT** an integer value. Use `null` instead (if the column in your table accepts nulls of course).

Comment: it's simple error. change `$rate` into integer or remove `'` single quotes on `$rate`

Comment: What is the full column type of `rate` ?

Comment: if you have numeric data type  you must remove the single quote around the related  var

Comment: 1. remove `quotes` around `$rate`.2. you need to add `null` or `0` as default value for that column in table.3.Code is wide open for `SQL INJECTION` so use `prepared statements`

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed int(11)

Comment: From your error - it looks as though you have no values for the data (all show as '').  Check how this page is called and the values being passed.

Comment: @SubramonianInian, before inserting, `echo` the value of `$rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments you should convert $rate into integer or remove `'` single quotes like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(   emp_name, 
                                rate, 
                                ifsc_code, 
                                acc_num, 
                                acc_holder_name) 

        VALUES              (   '$emp_name', 
                                $rate,
                                '$ifsc_code',
                                '$acc_num',
                                '$acc_holder_name')";
```

Or

you can convert into integer like this `$rate= (int)$rate;`

Also use `pdo` with bind parameter function for prevent `sql` injection

Comment: once i remove the quotes around $rate im getting an error saying ould not able to execute INSERT INTO employee( emp_name, rate, ifsc_code, acc_num, acc_holder_name) VALUES ( '', =(int), '', '', ''). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=(int), '', ''' at line 8

Comment: first you should only remove `'` on `$rate` and then execute query

Answer (score 0):

As noted above in a comment the original code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection so the use of a `prepared statement` would be advised to help mitigate risk.

The error message you posted though concerns me - it appears that all the values are empty... is that the case? You should check for the existence of these variables before attempting the sql operations.

```
<?php

    include_once('connectdb.php');

    try{

        $sql='insert into `employee` ( `emp_name`, `rate`, `ifsc_code`, `acc_num`, `acc_holder_name` ) values (?,?,?,?,?);';

        /* field names expected in REQUEST array and associated data type for filtering */
        $args=array(
            'emp_name'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'rate'              =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, /* assumed that rate is an integer */
            'ifsc_code'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'acc_num'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, /* assumed that acc_num is an integer ?? */
            'acc_holder_name'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        /* filter REQUEST array using above arguments */
        filter_input_array( INPUT_REQUEST, $args );

        /* extract variables */
        extract( $_REQUEST );


        /* If all the variables were extracted correctly after filtering - proceed */
        if( $emp_name && $rate && $ifsc_code && $acc_num && $acc_holder_name ){

            /* if the filter failed this will probably never be called but... */
            if( !is_integer( $rate ) ) throw new Exception('rate is not an integer');

            /* create a prepared statement */
            $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );

            /* If the query failed for some reason - abandon ship */
            if( !$stmt )throw new Exception( sprintf( 'error preparing sql query: %s', $stmt->error ) );

            /* assumed that rate and acc_num is an integer ?? */
            $stmt->bind_param( 'sisis', $emp_name, $rate, $ifsc_code, $acc_num, $acc_holder_name );

            /* execute the query */
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            if( $result ){

                echo "Success";


            } else {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( "Bogus! %s", $stmt->error ) );
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'an error occurred extracting one or more variables - check "$args" array!' );
        }

    } catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```